# In react.js i want to call a function after completing of scrolling not onScroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs

here, i got this suggestion to another post:-

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
}
componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll, true);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll, true);
}

handleScroll = () => {
    //any code
}
```

but handleScroll called each time when i scroll but i want to call this function after the scrolling is done.

Answer (score 0):

On top of my head there is no way to detect the end of a scroll event.

What you could do instead is use a setTimeout function, that would be reset on every scroll event. When the last one occurred, the setTimeout would go to its end and execute.

So that would give you something like:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.handleScrollTimeoutId = -1;
}

componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll, true);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
   window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll, true);
}

handleScroll = () => {
    clearTimeout(this.handleScrollTimeoutId);
    this.handleScrollTimeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
        // your code
    }, [your delay]);
}
```